# Algorithms behind this animated java applet

Tags: algorithm, animation, applet

I was recently happened to see this animation (http://universe.daylife.com/). I was wondering what are the algorithms behind this applet. How and Where to learn such things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, funny, I had lot of exceptions in the Java console, yet it kind of worked (changing colors, but not doing much other work, apparently).

Exceptions were:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at universe.draw(universe.java:262)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDisplay(PApplet.java:1359)
    at processing.core.PGraphics.requestDisplay(PGraphics.java:680)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

which reveal at least how the applet was done: by using the excellent [Processing](http://processing.org/) environment (using a "simplified" Java and a good graphics library).

Since it didn't really worked for me, I can hardly tell you how it was done (what it was supposed to do?), but well, you have at least a starting point! Note that Processing offers good tutorials too...

[EDIT] I re-tried with a standard search term (New-York instead of JavaFX...), and I got some result. Quite impressive.
Obviously, lot of work have been put there.
I confirm you can learn a lot on the algorithms used there (graphical, network, data parsing...) by browsing (and interacting!) on the Processing site and forum...